# Update with iBatis

Tags: ibatis, sql-update

I need to update the following table:

TOPICS =  where WORD_ID is a foreign key and both of them are the key of TOPICS.

I would like to query with iBatis:

```
UPDATE TOPICS 
SET TOPIC = #newTopic#
WHERE WORD_ID = #wordId#
AND TOPIC = #oldTopic#;
```

What's the way of using multiple parameters which are not only strings??

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

At java side build a HashMap

```
Map map = new HashMap();

map.add("NewTopic",aNewTopicValue );
map.add("OldTopic",anOldTopicValue );
map.add("WordId",aWordId );
```

Here the map values could be of any type (string or integer etc).

In Ibatis query specify parameterClass="map".

```
<update id="mySel" parameterClass="map">
UPDATE TOPICS
SET TOPIC = #NewTopic#
WHERE WORD_ID = #WordId#
AND TOPIC = #OldTopic#
</update>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify data type along with parameter like below

WHERE WORD_ID = #wordId:NUMERIC#

Answer (score 0):

```
<parameterMap class="ibatis.util.Entity" id="mySel_map">  
  <parameter property="NewTopic" jdbcType="VARCHAR" />      
  <parameter property="WordId" jdbcType="INT" />  
  <parameter property="OldTopic" jdbcType="VARCHAR" />  
</parameterMap>  

<update id="mySel" parameterMap="mySel_map">
      UPDATE TOPICS
      SET TOPIC = #NewTopic#
      WHERE WORD_ID = #WordId#
      AND TOPIC = #OldTopic#
</update>
```

Refer the above code. we can use the 'parameterMap' tag to map the parameter and specify the  `jdbcType` and `javaType`.